# GMLC server unable route the HTTP request due to SCCP routing error

Tags: xml, restcomm

I have been testing GMLC server with HLR simulator provided as a part of GMLC. I am running into a SCCP routing issue mentioned below, when I try to send a GMLC request (i.e. curl -X POST 171.10.30.19:8280/restcomm/gmlc/rest?msisdn=8476302000)

15:15:12,147 WARN  [SccpStackImpl-SccpStack] (pool-33-thread-1) Rx : MTP-RESUME: AffectedDpc=2

15:16:09,095 WARN  [SccpRoutingControl] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-7-thread-1) Received SccpMessage=Sccp Msg [Type=-1 networkId=0 sls=1 incomingOpc=-1 incomingDpc=-1 outgoingDpc=-1 CallingAddress(pc=0,ssn=145,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=6305629000, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=BCDEvenEncodingScheme[type=BCD_ODD, code=2]]) CalledParty(pc=0,ssn=6,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=8476302000, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=BCDEvenEncodingScheme[type=BCD_ODD, code=2]]) DataLen=76] for Translation but no local SSN is present for primary Address

I do notice that a few others encountered this issue and I followed all the configuration suggestions provided in the following links by

-- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mobicents-public/no$20local$20SSN$20is$20present$20for$20primary$20Address%7Csort:date/mobicents-public/grc_2TZ9O-Y/ZZIY977KEAAJ

-- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mobicents-public/no$20local$20SSN$20is$20present$20for$20primary$20Address%7Csort:date/mobicents-public/A4eyHSLnDXA/56-s0gnJQwAJ

Test environment:

```
GMLC Server
171.10.30.19
PC = 1 (ITU)
SSN = 145
GTT = 6305629000

HLR Simulator (or STP)
171.10.30.20
PC = 2 (ITU)
SSN = 6
GTT = 8476302000
```

Here are my SCCP configurations

**-- SccpStack_management2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <zmarginxudtmessage value="240"/>
 <reassemblytimerdelay value="15000"/>
 <maxdatamessage value="2560"/>
 <removespc value="true"/>
 <previewMode value="false"/>
 <sccpProtocolVersion value="ITU"/>
 <ssttimerduration_min value="10000"/>
 <ssttimerduration_max value="600000"/>
 <ssttimerduration_increasefactor value="1.5"/>
```

-- **SccpStack_sccpresource2.xml configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <remoteSsns>
        <id value="1"/>
        <value remoteSpc="2" remoteSsn="6" remoteSsnFlag="0" markProhibitedWhenSpcResuming="false"/>
     </remoteSsns>
     <remoteSpcs>
        <id value="1"/>
        <value remoteSpc="2" remoteSpcFlag="0" mask="0"/>
     </remoteSpcs>
     <concernedSpcs/>
```

**-- SccpStack_sccprouter2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
             <rule>
                     <id value="1"/>
                     <value ruleType="Solitary" loadSharingAlgo="Undefined" originatingType="RemoteOriginated" mask="K" paddress="1" saddress="-1" networkId="0">
                         <patternSccpAddress pc="0" ssn="0">
                                 <ai value="18"/>
                                 <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="2" np="1" nai="4" digits="6305629000"/>
                         </patternSccpAddress>
                 </value>
                 <id value="2"/>
                 <value ruleType="Solitary" loadSharingAlgo="Undefined" originatingType="LocalOriginated" mask="K" paddress="2" saddress="-1" networkId="0">
                         <patternSccpAddress pc="0" ssn="0">
                                 <ai value="16"/>
                                 <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="1" np="1" nai="4" digits="*"/>
                         </patternSccpAddress>
                 </value>
         </rule>
         <routingAddress>
                 <id value="1"/>
                 <sccpAddress pc="1" ssn="145">
                         <ai value="19"/>
                         <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="2" np="1" nai="4" digits="6305629000"/>
                 </sccpAddress>
                   <id value="2"/>
                   <sccpAddress pc="2" ssn="6">
                           <ai value="17"/>
                           <gt type="GT0100" tt="0" es="1" np="1" nai="4" digits="*"/>
                   </sccpAddress>
            </routingAddress>
            <longMessageRule/>
            <sap>
                     <id value="1"/>
                     <value mtp3Id="1" opc="2" ni="2" networkId="1">
                             <mtp3DestinationMap>
                                     <id value="1"/>
                                     <value firstDpc="1" lastDpc="16384" firstSls="0" lastSls="255" slsMask="255"/>
                             </mtp3DestinationMap>
                     </value>
            </sap>
```

**--TcapStack_management.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dialogidletimeout value="60000"/>
<invoketimeout value="30000"/>
<maxdialogs value="5000"/>
<dialogidrangestart value="1"/>
<dialogidrangeend value="2147483647"/>
<donotsendprotocolversion value="false"/>
<statisticsenabled value="false"/>
```

The TCAP service bean parameter in ~/RestComm/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/restcomm-gmlc-server/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml is set to 145 (i.e. GMLC SSN)

```
<bean name="GMLC_TcapStack" class="org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.tcap.TCAPStackImpl">
        <constructor>
           <parameter>TcapStack</parameter>
           <parameter>
               <inject bean="GMLC_SccpStack" property="sccpProvider" />
           </parameter>
           <parameter>145</parameter>
        </constructor>
        <property name="persistDir">${jboss.server.data.dir}</property>
        <!--
        <property name="dialogIdleTimeout">60000</property>
        <property name="invokeTimeout">30000</property>
        <property name="maxDialogs">25000</property >
        -->
   </bean>
```

The GMLC code base is from the latest master branch and I am using the ZIP file created by the GMLC server build process. Please let me know, if I am missing something in the configuration or making some mistakes in the test environment itself. I don't see any issues with SCTP association and functioning of M3UA and SCCP initialization. It's something to do with SCCP routing rule configuration that uses primary address config from "routingAddress" config section.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,

Ashok